# Get host from where script has been requested

Tags: javascript

I have a script that other people request on their websites from my host. I have multiple environments (dev/test/production), and within my script, I want to know the environment from which it has been loaded.

For example, I'm serving `script.js` at the following sites (the file is the same on all sites):

```
dev.mysite.com/script.js
test.mysite.com/script.js
www.mysite.com/script.js
```

Someone loads my script as:

```
<script src="dev.mysite.com/script.js"></script>
```

So within `script.js`, I want to have some code which is able to get the host from which the script itself has been requested from:

```
var getHost = function() {
  var host = // host from where it has been requested
  return host; // in this case it should return dev.mysite.com
};
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: [`window.location.origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location)?

Comment: You _could_ iterate and check the length (within the script itself) of each script tag inside the document, and check the src, but that really would be going to a lot of trouble for what seems to be a simple thing.

Comment: @vol7ron: I certainly thought that "_it should return dev.mysite.com_" was clear - but if we even need to say this it probably could have been worded in a better way.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy you're right, my reading skills are not well this morning.

Comment: (to correct my comment earlier) Actually, since you cannot get the length of an externally linked script, it unfortunately becomes impossible to do so if even one of them is cross-domain.

Comment: Now that I'm awake, I'm curious as to why.  Why does your script need to be self-aware? If you're hosting the files, couldn't your webserver do the filtering to the respective file? eg `dev.mysite.com/script.js => /env/dev/js/devscript.js` and `test.mysite.com/script.js => /env/test/js/testscript.js`?  If you want in one location, then why not use a server-side script to generate the JS? Sort of like: `<domain>/scriptHost.pl?name=script.js` which will return the JS and do any request header parsing you please.  I guess what I'm getting at is self-aware JS is most likely unnecessary and bloated

Comment: @vol7ron I have dev/test/production branchs on github, each one pushed to a different subdomain in heroku. My users are loading this js file to embed a widget on their website. The js comes in pair with a css.. so I want to know where did the user requested the js file in order to serve the correct css (dev is cutting edge, while production hosts older stable version). A mismatch between the css and js may broke the script.

Comment: @jviotti: it sounds like this might be something you want to handle with your webserver (assuming Apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had difficulty in understanding what you're really after, but you can loop through all the scripts and parse the `src`.

jQuery:

```
function getHosts(scriptName){
   var hosts  = [];
   scriptName = scriptName.replace(/([.])/g,"\\$1"); // escape special characters

   $('script').each(function(){
      var _src    = this.src;

      if ( RegExp(scriptName).test(_src) ){
         _src = _src.replace(/^https*:\/\//,'');     // remove protocol
         _src = _src.replace(/\/.*$/,'');            // remove rest of path
         hosts[hosts.length] = _src;                 // store it for return
      }
   });

   return hosts;                                     // return results as array
}

alert( getHosts('script.js').join(',') );
```

---

And w/o jQuery:

```
function getHosts(scriptName){
   var hosts  = [];
   scriptName = scriptName.replace(/([.])/g,"\\$1"); // escape special characters

   var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
   for (var n=scripts.length;n--;){
      var _src = scripts[n].src;

      if ( RegExp(scriptName).test(_src) ){
         _src = _src.replace(/^https*:\/\//,'');     // remove protocol
         _src = _src.replace(/\/.*$/,'');            // remove rest of path
         hosts[hosts.length] = _src;                 // store it for return
      }
   }

   return hosts;                                     // return results as array
}

alert( getHosts('test.js').join('\n') );
```

Comment: window.location.host only tells you where the document containing the script comes from, not where the script itself originates.

Comment: Since when do JavaScript files have their own scope? `window` (and therefore `window.location` refer to the main HTML page that included the script. `window.location` will **not** refer to the script's location

Comment: @Simon that's what he's asking

Comment: @Ian he wants the location of the local page calling the file, thus it will have a `window` or `document`

Comment: **No** he doesn't. He's **serving** the JS file at those 3 locations. ANY page (`http://www.google.com/`, `http://www.example.com`, `http://www.jquery.com/`) can request it from those 3 locations. He wants to know **which** of those 3 locations was it requested from, **not** the containing document

Comment: I think he wants the environment of his domain that is serving the file. Not the host that included it. Other people are including his file and he wants to know if they're including dev, or live etc. The question clearly states "I want to know the environment from which it has been loaded."

Comment: @vol7ron That's definitely better :) I'm not exactly sure how the OP expects to use it, so I think something more like this would work

Comment: This worked to me. The script source loading is part of an embed object, so within the embedded code, I attached an ID to the script tag, so I could fetch it easier later :) Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @jviotti: I just left a comment on your question for other things to think about

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible without some changes to the way you serve your scripts. I believe you need to hard code the host name into some variable your script declares, and change that as your script file moves from `dev` to `test` to `www`. Alternatively, you can insert the value dynamically using e.g. PHP.

**Example:** In your script, you'll have something like

```
var myscript = {
    // declare a 'namespace'
    stage = '__STAGE_PLACEHOLDER__';

    myfunc = function(args) {
        ...

    }

    // your code goes here
};
```

Before you serve it, have `__STAGE_PLACEHOLDER__` replaced by `dev` / `test` / `www`, and then you can introspect using `myscript.stage`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the env to depend on the path of the script, not the page which included it, then `window.location` won't work. What you could do is have a different js script for each env, with a custom `getHost()` function in it, i.e:

```
var getHost = function () {
  return "dev";
}
```

To avoid the overhead of having multiple scripts you could generate this additional function on the fly on the server side.

You could also ask the user to define the environment himself, i.e:

```
MyApp.config.env = 'dev';
```

Answer (score -1):

From the Mozilla developer site reference for `window.location`:

```
window.location.hostname // the host name (without the port number or square brackets)
```